# Store an integer in char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

Running the code below prints `b =  and i = 15`.

```
int i = 15;
char b = (char) i;
printf("b = %c and i = %d\n", b, i);
```

How can I store this integer in the character? At the end I'm trying to have a char array of size 1024 which has `i` (15) as the first character and rest 0.

update: I tried :

```
int i = 15;
char buffer[1024];
snprintf(buffer, 10, "%d", i);
printf("buffer[0] = %c, buffer[1] = %c\n", buffer[0], buffer[1]);
```

And the result printed was:

> buffer[0] = 1 , buffer[1] = 5

Comment: You say `i=15` and you want `b`  to equal 15 as well if Im not mistaken but 15 isnt a character. You cant hold 2 characters (1 and 5) in a single character variable (b).I may be misunderstanding your question though.

Comment: You will want to visit [**http://www.asciitable.com/**](http://www.asciitable.com/) and familiarize yourself with the ASCII values for printable characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did store the integer in the character, it's just that `%c` converts a character to its ASCII value. All ASCII values below 31 are non-printable.

If you run

```
printf("b = %d and i = %d\n", (int)b, i);
```

it will print 15.

If you want a representation of `i` as a string:

```
char buf[12]; //Maximum number of digits in i, plus one for the terminating null
snprintf(buf, 12, "%d", i);
```

This will store a string representation of `i` in `buf`.

Comment: I tried:  char buffer[1024];
                    snprintf(buffer, 1, "%d", i);
                    printf("buffer[0] = %c, buffer[1] = %c\n", buffer[0], buffer[1]);  But i'm still not getting 1 and 5 for buffer (i=15)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `snprintf(buf, 10, "%d", i);`?

Comment: @Dmitri Oops. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @NickyMirfallah As Dimitri mentioned, I had a minor typo. `char buffer[1024]; snprintf(buffer, 1024, "%d", i); printf("buffer[0] = %c, buffer[1] = %c\n", buffer[0], buffer[1]);` should work. Note that`printf("%s\n", buffer);` will print out the whole string ("15" in this case).

Comment: Hmmm, typical `int` can store the value of -2,147,483,648.  Magic number 10 is insufficient for a string that may need size 12.

Comment: @chux The comment next to the declaration was meant as an instruction to change it based on the range of values needed for the application, not a claim that 10 is the number needed. But good point. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, variable `b` already has a value `15` but since this does not constitute to a printable ASCII, using `%c` format specifier, you won't be able to see any *output*.

To print the value, use `%hhd` format specifier.

> *At the end I'm trying to have a char array of size 1024 which has i (15) as the first character and rest 0.*

Well, you can define an array and assign values accordingly. Something like

```
#define SIZE 1024

char arr [SIZE] = {0}; //initialization, fill all with 0
arr[0] = 15;           //first value is 15
```

should do the job.

Comment: `%hhd` converts the integer argument to `signed char` before printing. `char` might not be `signed char`.  IAC, `printf("b = %dn", b);` is sufficient unless rare `char` is same width/signness as `unsigned`.

Answer (score 1):

A char is an 8-bit unsigned value (0 - 255) and it does indeed store 15 in it, the problem is, that in ASCII table 15 means "shift in" non-printable character, and %c interprets the value as an ascii character.

```
char b = (char) i;
printf("b = %d and i = %d\n", b, i);
```

to get

> b = 15 and i = 15

if you used `i = 90` in your current code, this would be printed:

> b = Z and i = 90

Comment: `char` isn't always unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Clarification:

The range of char is -128..127.
The range of unsigned char is 0..255.

If capturing ASCII values is the goal,  declaring buffer variable to unsigned char type seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart) values are in the range 0 to 127 and can be saved in `char` , `unsigned chart`, or `signed char`.

Comment: Yes. But any ASCII value that is  greater than 127 will require unsigned char type.

Comment: Since ASCII is defined in the range 0 to 127, "ASCII value that is greater than 127" is a false premise.  Perhaps you are thing of various [extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) to ASCII?

Comment: Yes.  I am considering ASCII extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store Integer datatype in Character datatype(**datatype conflict**).
But what you are want, can be achieved by taking 2-dimensional character array.

```
char b[1024][1024];
itoa(i,b[0],20); /// 
for(int i = 1 ; i < 1024 ; i++)
    itoa(0,b[i],20);
```

Function **itoa** converts integer into character array and stores it into the character array. Hope it helps.

[click here for more info :)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/)

Comment: `char b = (char) i;` is fine.  "You can't store Integer datatype in Character datatype" is not supported by the C spec.  `char` is an integer type.